# SMTP send attachment

Tags: email, smtp, network-protocols

I am learning networking recently.

It is known that SMTP only allows 7-bit ASCII.

I would like to know if SMTP can send attachment such as pictures, videos or files via email. If so, how can the attachment be sent?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SMTP, almost every email is using MIME (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions, [RFC2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)). MIME is independent of SMTP, but can be thought like extension to it. HTTP protocol is also using MIME.

MIME contains two parts. MIME headers and MIME content. MIME headers describe what the contents will be. MIME is full of features, but I'm only describing what is relevant to your question.

MIME headers of interest:

- `Content-Type` describe what the content is. Simply, text is just `text/plain` and `image/jpeg` is JPEG image.
- `Content-Transfer-Encoding` describe how the content is encoded. Common encodings in email are [`quoted-printable`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-6.7) and `base64`. These encodings are designed for SMTP's 7bit delivery in mind.
- `Content-Disposition` header contains for example attachments file name.

For sending attachment or multiple attachments, each attachment is encoded as described above (some headers + encoded content). First `Content-Type` header is set to `multipart/mixed` and given `boundary` tag like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=4vvtTcl0dIpecpyi12ab54
```

And every attachment (headers + content) starts with boundary tag:

```
--4vvtTcl0dIpecpyi12ab54
```

followed by MIME headers and then contents. This way the email client can separate attachments from each other.

I would also like to mention that there is 8BITMIME extension to SMTP for 8 bit support. See [RFC6152: SMTP Service Extension for 8-bit MIME Transport](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6152).